# In a multi-module GWT application with one entry point, is there a way to run GWT tests from sub modules only in the entry point GWT module?

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, testing, maven

As an additional note, we manage our project builds with Maven.

Let's say we have three GWT modules, only one of which has an entry point. The other two modules are inherited by the module containing the entry point.

We practice MVP and strive to keep the majority of our testing as normal JUnit tests, but some integration tests require us to use GWTTest. We keep these to a minimum.

We would like to keep the actual tests with the modules containing the code they are testing. My thought was to ensure that maven only executes JUnit tests for the sub-module builds. The GWTTests in the submodules would be rolled up into a test suite. Then, the entry point project would contain a GWTTestSuite which rolls up the submodule test suites along with and other GWTTests that the entry point module may have.

At this point, my problem is that the entry point GWTTestSuite can't resolve the tests from the submodules (`"no source code is available........did you forget to inherit a required module"`). I've tried creating the test-jars for the submodules and adding them as dependencies to the test scope, but when GWT is executing the primary GWTTestSuite, it can't find the submodule test suites (or their underlying gwt tests). I can see the GWTTests in the .m2 repo test jars.

So, how do I get the GWT compiler to "see" the submodule tests?

Update:
I have not yet been able to figure out how to do this. The cleanest thing I can manage is to keep the normal JUnit tests co-located with the submodules, but keep all GWT Tests for all modules in the main module.

Comment: I've resorted to stalking the [CodeHaus Mojo GWT Maven Plugin Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users) google group for answers. I will post answer if I can find one :)

Comment: Create test.gwt.xml and inherit there all gwt submodules. In test.gwt.xml define entry point. I use [gwt-test-utils](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/) - it is faster. Version 0.40+ compiles all files and requires source code. See [gwt-test-utils sample](https://github.com/gwt-test-utils/gwt-test-utils-samples)